# Memcache conflict with mongodb?

Tags: 6, caching, database

I tried to install memcache module and mongodb in Drupal 6. When I enable memcache, the mongodb will not work.

Comment: Any specific error messages or debugging information?  WSoD, etc?

Comment: Not any errors or warnings